# Delphi deserialize JSON with abstract class

Tags: json, delphi, deserialization, abstract-class

I want to serialize and deserialize an object with the built-in functions `TJson.JsonToObject<T>` and `TJson.ObjectToJsonObject`. The object contains some nested objects and one of these is of an abstract type. Is there any chance, to tell the deserializer, which concrete object to create? Can I maybe use a custom JSONInterceptor for this nested object?

The classes are defined as following:

```
type
  TAngPos = class (TObject)
    strict private
      var
        FPrimkey: Integer;
        FAng_ID: Integer;
        FPosNr: Integer;
        FArt_ID: Integer;
      
        FPositionstyp: TPositionstyp; // <--- abstract
  end;
```

```
type
  TPositionstyp = class abstract (TObject)
    strict protected
      var
        FArtikel: TArtikel;
  end;
```

```
type
  TPositionstypArtikel = class (TPositionstyp);
```

```
type
  TPositionstypAngPosKonf = class (TPositionstyp)
    strict private
      var
        FGrundeinheit: TAngPos;
        FEinbaukomponenten: TObjectList<TAngPos>;
  end;
```

```
type
  TArtikel = class (TObject)
    strict private
      var
        FPrimkey: Integer;
        FStatus: Integer;
        FTyp: Integer;
        FBeschreibung: string;
        FHerstellerNr: string;
  end;
```

The corresponding JSON looks like this:

for TPositionstypArtikel:

```
{
  "primkey": 23930,
  "ang_ID": 2400,
  "posNr": 40,
  "art_ID": 46210,
  "positionstyp": { // PositionstypArtikel
    "artikel": {
      "primkey": 46210,
      "status": 1,
      "typ": 2,
      "beschreibung": "MyDescription",
      "herstellerNr": "MyVendorNr"
    }
  }
}
```

and for TPositionstypAngPosKonf

```
{
    "primkey": 2,
    "ang_ID": 1,
    "posNr": 10,
    "art_ID": 44041,
    "positionstyp": { // TPositionstypAngPosKonf
      "grundeinheit": { // <-- TAngPos
        "primkey": 33067,
        "ang_ID": 0,
        "posNr": 20,
        "art_ID": 44092,
        "positionstyp": {
          "artikel": {
            "primkey": 44092,
            "status": 2,
            "typ": 4,
            "beschreibung": "MyDescriptionGrundeinheit",
            "herstellerNr": "MyVendorNrGrundeinheit"
          }
        }
      },
      "einbaukomponenten": { // <-- TObjectList<TAngPos>
        "ownsObjects": true,
        "listHelper": [
          {
            "primkey": 33068,
            "ang_ID": 0,
            "posNr": 30,
            "art_ID": 44399,
            "positionstyp": {
              "artikel": {
                "primkey": 44399,
                "status": 2,
                "typ": 4,
                "beschreibung": "MyDescriptionEinbaukomponente1",
                "herstellerNr": "MyVendorNrEinbaukomponente1"
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "primkey": 33069,
            "ang_ID": 0,
            "posNr": 40,
            "art_ID": 44398,
            "positionstyp": {
              "artikel": {
                "primkey": 44398,
                "status": 2,
                "typ": 4,
                "beschreibung": "MyDescriptionEinbaukomponente2",
                "herstellerNr": "MyVendorNrEinbaukomponente2"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "artikel": {
        "primkey": 44041,
        "status": 1,
        "typ": 3,
        "beschreibung": "MyDescriptionKonfKopf",
        "herstellerNr": ""
      }
    }
```

After deserialization of the object, I can check, if the nested object is of a specific type with the `is`-operator, but unfortunately it's neither `TPositionstypArtikel` nor `TPositionstypAngPosKonf`.

Comment: How do you distinguish which of the derived types shall be returned from the JSON string?

Comment: One of the derived classes contains additional nested objects, so I can distinguish them by the structure of the JSON string.

Comment: Can you provide a simple example (class declarations and JSON strings)?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot see a way to achieve that with TJson.JsonToObject<T> as you cannot see the JSON content when deciding which type to use for a field. You might have more luck by introducing some superclass that combines the fields of all possible inherited classes. For the case shown just TPositionstypAngPosKonf would do, but that is rather a corner case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the comments. I ended up in changing the structure of the class. It doesn't contain the abstract type anymore, but rather a separate variable of type `TPositionstypAngPosKonf`, which is either `nil` or not. The `TArtikel` from the `TPositionstyp` now inhabits directly in the `TAngPos` and the two classes `TPositionstyp` and `TPositionstypArtikel` don't exist anymore. So it basically looks like this

```
type
  TAngPos = class (TObject)
    strict private
      var
        FPrimkey: Integer;
        FAng_ID: Integer;
        FPosNr: Integer;
        FArt_ID: Integer;
      
        FArtikel: TArtikel;
        FPositionstypAngPosKonf: TPositionstypAngPosKonf; // may be nil
  end;
```

```
type
  TPositionstypAngPosKonf = class (TObject)
    strict private
      var
        FGrundeinheit: TAngPos;
        FEinbaukomponenten: TObjectList<TAngPos>;
  end;
```

```
type
  TArtikel = class (TObject)
    strict private
      var
        FPrimkey: Integer;
        FStatus: Integer;
        FTyp: Integer;
        FBeschreibung: string;
        FHerstellerNr: string;
  end;
```